# Wildfly 9.0.0 and Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, netbeans, wildfly

I've been moved from JBoss AS 7.1.1 to WildFly 9.0.0. When I try to debug the application, it fails starting and the following message is shown:

*C:...\build-impl.xml:1181: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.*

build-impl.xml:1181:

```
    <nbstartserver debugmode="true"/>
    <antcall target="connect-debugger"/>
    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="true" forceRedeploy="true"/>
    <antcall target="debug-display-browser-old"/>
    <antcall target="debug-display-browser"/>
    <antcall target="connect-client-debugger"/>
```

logs:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
03:39:35,677 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.4.3.Final
03:39:35,995 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.4.Final
03:39:36,104 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 9.0.0.CR1 (WildFly Core 1.0.0.CR1) starting
03:39:38,077 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute enabled is deprecated, and it might be removed in future version!
03:39:38,080 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute enabled is deprecated, and it might be removed in future version!
03:39:38,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
03:39:38,223 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
03:39:38,254 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
03:39:38,368 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
03:39:38,371 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
03:39:38,398 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.0.Beta2
03:39:38,409 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
03:39:38,449 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
03:39:38,451 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
03:39:38,503 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
03:39:38,551 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.4.Final starting
03:39:38,555 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.2.4.Final starting
03:39:38,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
03:39:38,598 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
03:39:38,628 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.2.4.Final)
03:39:38,645 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
03:39:38,666 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
03:39:38,868 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql
03:39:38,905 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
03:39:38,909 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
03:39:39,111 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path C:\WildFly/welcome-content
03:39:39,174 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
03:39:39,215 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
03:39:39,241 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
03:39:39,379 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:150)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:182)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:243)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.HttpListenerService.startListening(HttpListenerService.java:115)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:147)
    ... 5 more

03:39:39,892 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\WildFly\standalone\deployments
03:39:40,024 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:269)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.start(ManagementHttpServer.java:160)
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:235)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:182)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:243)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ManagementHttpServer.start(ManagementHttpServer.java:147)
    ... 6 more

03:39:40,092 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
03:39:40,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/booking-war]
03:39:40,102 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"},
    "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http.shutdown"],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
    }
}
03:39:40,106 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "webservices")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.ws.config"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
}}
03:39:40,107 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("http-listener" => "default")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.listener.default" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"}}
03:39:40,110 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "ejb3")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => [
        "jboss.ejb.default-local-ejb-receiver-service",
        "jboss.ejb3.ejbClientContext.default",
        "jboss.ejb3.localEjbReceiver.value"
    ],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
}}
03:39:40,113 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "ejb3"),
    ("service" => "remote")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.ejb3.connector is missing [jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector]"]}
03:39:40,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ejb3.connector] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener
      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: WFLYSRV0083: Failed to start the http-interface service

03:39:40,515 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0063: Http management interface is not enabled
03:39:40,515 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0054: Admin console is not enabled
03:39:40,515 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 9.0.0.CR1 (WildFly Core 1.0.0.CR1) started (with errors) in 5244ms - Started 191 of 381 services (8 services failed or missing dependencies, 210 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you already have something listening on port 8080

Comment: I've looked for netstat and nothing uses this port. I've also changed port to 8081 and 8088 - nothing changes

Comment: Per the error message you definitely have something listening on the http port and http management port. Maybe you're launching it twice somehow.

Answer (score 0):

1. Nvidia actually takes ports needed for wildfly. Use offset parameter in wildfly config file to shift all wildfly ports. I use offset=100.
2. Netbeans 8.0.2' wildfly plugin doesn't work. When you first try to start application, it starts wildfly, but doesn't stop it after. When you try to start application second time, Wildfly already runs (because it was not properly shutdowned by NetBeans/plugin), and wildfly ports, obviously, are in use. That is what wildfly is complaints about. Workaround is to use wildfly cli to manually start/stop the server.

Answer (score -1):

Nvidia service is the problem: it runs in a hihden proces which blocks http:localhost:8080\console

Try kill all nvidia processes

Answer (score -1):

I too had similar issue and while starting the wildfly, in my system already an application was running on port 8080, uninstalled that application then wildfly 10 was started without the bind exception.